# "Cannot resolve method 'run(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String[])'" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I don't understand why the main method of my Spring Boot application is red-underlined. The application runs properly and no other issues are visible. Maybe somebody could help me with an answer to this.
I'm attaching a picture of the main method:

[image: Main class print screen1]

Comment: Please, provide more information, logs, screens and more details.

Comment: Does removing the `, args` work?